# Demonstration that the $\langle f(x)\rangle$ of an odd function $f(x)=-f(-x)$ of position $x$ in a symmetric potential well $V(x)=V(-x)$ is null

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, probability, parity

Consider a potential infinite well, which borders are $x=-a$ and $x=a$. I pretend to demonstrate that the expected value of a odd function $f(x)$, i.e., $\langle f(x)\rangle$, is null.

We have the following wave function: $$\psi(x,t)=\sum_n A_n u_n(x) e^{-\frac{iE_n}{\hbar}t}$$
I know that for a symmetric potential infinite well, the eigenfunctions $u(x)$ of $H$ are real, and have a defined parity. So,

$$\langle f(x)\rangle=\int_{-a}^{a}\text{dx } \psi^*(x)f(x)\psi(x)=\int_{-a}^{a}\text{dx } \left(\sum_n A_n u_n(x)\right)f(x)\left(\sum_n A_n u_n(x)\right)$$

$\langle f(x)\rangle$ will be null if only $u_n(x)$ and $u_m(x)f(x),$ where ($n\neq m)$ are orthogonal.

Is it true that if $u_n(x)$ and $u_m(x)$ are orthogonal (which is true), then $u_n(x)$ and $u_m(x)f(x)$ will be also orthogonal?

Comment: The expected value of $f(x)$ is $\int_{-a}^{+a} f(x)\mathrm dx$, irrespective or the nature of the potential. If $f$ is odd, then $\langle f\rangle=0$ because of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Basic_calculus_properties) (wikipedia link).

Comment: I know that statement, but the expected value is $<f(x)>=\int_{-a}^{a}\text{dx } \psi^*(x)f(x)\psi(x)$ and not $<f(x)>=\int_{-a}^{a} f(x)\text{dx}$.

Comment: yes of course. nevertheless, write $g(x)=f(x)|\psi(x)|^2$, and everything works out just fine, because $g(x)$ is odd whenever $f(x)$ is.

Comment: @qftishard:  The problem is that $|\psi(x)|^2$ is not necessarily an even or odd function.  See my answer below.

Comment: youre right. if $\psi(x)$ is an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian, then it *does* have well defined parity (or can be taken to). If its time dependence is non-trivial, though, $\langle f\rangle\neq 0$ in general. If we want $\langle f(t)\rangle=0$ we must have, at $t=0$, $f(x)=\pm f(-x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it true that if $u_n(x)$ and $u_m(x)$ are orthogonal (which is true), then $u_n(x)$ and $u_m(x)f(x)$ will be also orthogonal?

No.  The simplest example of this is the case $f(x) = u_n(x)/u_m(x)$ for whatever $n$ and $m$ you're considering.

More broadly, the result you're trying to prove is false.  Consider the infinite square well between $\pm \pi/2$, with the wavefunction $\psi(x) = \cos(x) + \sin(2x)$:

[image]

The expectation value of $f(x) = x$ is quite obviously not zero, even though $f(x)$ is an odd function, and in fact works out to be $\langle x \rangle = 16/9\pi.$

Now, if $\psi$ happens to be an eigenstate of parity, then I think your result holds:  If $P \psi(x) = \pm \psi(x)$ (where $P$ is the parity operator), then $\psi^*(x) \psi(x)$ is obviously an even function, which means that $\psi^*(x) \psi(x) f(x)$ is an odd function, and we get zero when we integrate it over an even interval.  What's more, if the potential is itself symmetric, then $[H, P] = 0$ and all of the energy eigenstates $u_n(x)$ are (or can be chosen to be) parity eigenstates.  But if you're combining states of different parity (which you seem to want to do), then all bets are off.

Comment: Another easy way to see it has to be false is that it would imply that it is impossible to have any state at any time where $\langle X \rangle \ne 0$. However, we know from daily experience that there are such states by looking at the classical limit of a pendulum or harmonic oscillator, because there we clearly see the object moving back and forth.

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs:  Yes, I should also note that this is the expectation value of $x$ at a particular moment in time.  As the two components of the above wavefunction evolve in time, their relative phases will change, causing the value of $\langle x \rangle$ to oscillate.